# Create junitTest or cactus test for servlet

Tags: testing, servlets, junit, cactus

I have the following Servlet method which I want to create test for it using junit or Cactus. I'm a newbie so I will really appreciate any tips.

```
public DSResponse executeFetch(DSRequest req) throws Exception {
    DSResponse resp = new DSResponse();

    String maID = (String) req.getCriteria().get("memberActivityID");
    MemberActivityImpl memberImpl = new MemberActivityImpl();

    MemberActivity memberAct = new MemberActivity();

    if (req.getDataSourceName().equals("memberActivity")) {
    if (maID != null) {
    // Fetch the MemberActivity based on the memberActivityID criteria
    memberAct = memberImpl.getMemberActivity(maID);

    List<Map> resultList = new LinkedList<Map>();

    if( memberAct != null && memberAct.getMemberID() != null )
        // Pass the memberAct to the client
        Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        result.put("name", memberAct.getName());
        result.put("type", memberAct.getType());
        result.put("memberID", memberAct.getMemberID());
        if (memberAct.getGoal() != null) {
            result.put("goal", memberAct.getGoal());}
            resultList.add(result);
        }
        resp.setData(resultList);
    } else {
        resp.setFailure();
    }
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: The quesiton is how to test this servlet's method using either Junit or cactus .

Comment: So what have you tried? See http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Hi Matthew, I am little bit confused about what is the best way to test SmartServer serlvets?I have tried Junit tests but to test Implementation classes only, not servlet I'm newbie to test webservices.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is best way to test smartServer servlets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332268/what-is-best-way-to-test-smartserver-servlets)

Comment: Hi Matthew if you have the answer please just say it

Comment: I don't know the answer, sorry.